# 1999 Honda Accord HVAC gets stuck on dash mode

Tags: honda, accord, hvac

The HVAC on my 1999 Honda Accord gets stuck on the dash mode.  All of the control buttons work and I can cycle from one to the other until I put it on dash only mode.  Once there, the motor stops working.  I have removed the mode motor assembly and manually moved the disc inside the assembly, reinstalled it, and the motor works fine again until I put the HVAC on dash-only mode.  I've cleaned all of the contacts inside the mode motor assembly to no avail.  Has anyone else been able to fix this type of problem without replacing the $200-300 mode motor assembly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!